# Polish Date Format in rich:calendar results in error

Tags: jsf, calendar, locale, richfaces

I have a standard JSF richfaces calendar (using JSF 2.2.18 and richfaces 4.5.16) where the default datePattern is "MMM dd, yyyy"

```
<rich:calendar id="startDate"
    value="#{startDate}"
    popup="true" dayDisableFunction="isProfileDayEnabled"
    dayClassFunction="getDisabledDateStyle" showWeeksBar="false" timeZone="#{timeZone}"
    datePattern="#{facesCalendar.datePattern}"
    showApplyButton="false" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px"
    style="width:200px" direction="#{calendarDirection}" jointPoint="#{calendarPosition}"
    styleClass="noToday" showFooter="false">
```

Everything is fine until we switch Locale to Polish. We can still select a date, but we then get this error

```
alertFormId:startDate: 'paÅº 16, 2018' could not be understood as a date.
alertFormId:endDate: 'paÅº 17, 2018' could not be understood as a date.
```

With a simple unit test, i can verify that date string is converted correctly

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy",new Locale("pl", "PL"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
-->paź 17, 2018
```

It seems that the translation/convertion of the month 'października' -> 'paź' is not encoded correctly in richfaces. I'm wondering is there a suggested workaround for this?

Comment: Well... Clearly you have something wrong with encoding. Set UTF-8 for the whole app (one global encoding is basically a good idea). I can use this pattern without any problem. It's not about polish and it's not about RF :)

Comment: And BTW.: 'Polish Date Format', no one in Poland will use this format. It's dd.mm.yyyy (informal) or yyyy-mm-dd (formal).

Comment: I guess i'd expect some language bundle in jsf or richfaces to have a polish local specific mapping woth October=października and Oct=Paź but i can't find such a file to override it.

Comment: It has to be in some RF's JavaScript files, although I don't know why you want to override anything. Like I said. There's nothing wrong with RF nor JSF. Debug the encoding.